# Why is the code in the vs code ipynb grey and how can I change that?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

[image]

I have the following problem with the highlighting of my visual studio code.

Comment: For native ipynb, in the cell `Esc, Y` and `Esc, M` will toggle between code and markup.

Comment: These look like markdown code blocks, not runnable cells

Comment: I solved it. But maybe @OneCricketeer you could elaborate. However, I feel like that was not the reason. I disabled the Redhat dependency analytics extension as well as installed the MagicPython extension

Comment: It was definitely the Redhat Dependency Analytics application. I don't really know why. But it works now even without MagicPython.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself by disabling the Redhat Dependency Analytics extension.